# Is it possible to change filenames in media library after upload?

Tags: media

Having issue with å,ä,ö when moved to another host, so I have to change filenames where å,ä,ö exists. Is this possible or do I have to save all images with these characters and then upload them again?

Answer (score 0):

Just found that I could show attachment page , and then edit the filename from there.